# ImportError: libhdf5.so.200: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (while importing pycbc.waveform)

Tags: python-3.x, importerror, hdf5, ubuntu-20.04, h5py

I have installed LALSuite and pycbc on my Ubuntu 20.04LTS python3.8 virtual environment. But when I am trying to import some library such as pycbc.waveform I get the following error:

**ImportError: libhdf5.so.200: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

When I checked my h5py.libs file in the location: **/home/abhijeet/lal/lib/python3.8/site-packages**

I have four files in it with the names:

**libaec-9c9e97eb.so.0.0.10**

**libhdf5-346dbfc8.so.200.1.0**

**libhdf5_hl-84bfe2a0.so.200.0.1**

**libsz-090daab4.so.2.0.1**

I have tried to uninstall h5py and reinstall it but it doesn't work. Please help me to rectify this error.

Comment: You could try `ln -s libhdf5-346dbfc8.so.200.1.0 libhdf5.so.200` , which is like the Fedora 36 "hdf5-1.12.1" providing `libhdf5.so.200 -> libhdf5.so.200.1.0`

Comment: @KnudLarsen Thanks for you suggestion. I tried creating the symbolic link as suggested by you. But again the same error is coming up.

Comment: If the error is just "not found", either copy the files to a system LD_LIBRARY_PATH , ..... or point to the file(s) with `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=[actual location]`

Comment: @KnudLarsen I have exported to the actual location but still the problem is there.